# DJANGO - "SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server" - error

Tags: django, django-email

I have an app where I'm testing email sending with django. The django project is still and development and I'm using the default sqlite3 as database. I have configured the EMAIL_BACKEND, EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TSL and EMAIL_USE_SSLfields in my app_name/settings.py. I am trying to send the email with a default personal gmail.com

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<username@gmail.com>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<app_password>'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TSL = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
```

And I'm trying to send the email in the python powershell like this:

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: from django.core.mail import send_mail

In [3]: send_mail(subject='Add an eye-catching subject', message='Write an amazing message', from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, fail_silently=False, 
   ...:  recipient_list=['<username@gmail.com>'])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SMTPNotSupportedError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 send_mail(subject='Add an eye-catching subject', message='Write an amazing message', from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, fail_silently=False, recipient_list=['<username@gmail.com>'])

File C:\PATH\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py:87, in send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, auth_user, auth_password, connection, html_message)
     84 if html_message:
     85     mail.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
---> 87 return mail.send()

File C:\PATH\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py:298, in EmailMessage.send(self, fail_silently)
    294 if not self.recipients():
    295     # Don't bother creating the network connection if there's nobody to
    296     # send to.
    297     return 0
--> 298 return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File C:\PATH\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py:127, in EmailBackend.send_messages(self, email_messages)
    125     return 0
    126 with self._lock:
--> 127     new_conn_created = self.open()
    128     if not self.connection or new_conn_created is None:
    129         # We failed silently on open().
    130         # Trying to send would be pointless.
    131         return 0

File C:\PATH\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py:94, in EmailBackend.open(self)
     92         self.connection.starttls(context=self.ssl_context)
     93     if self.username and self.password:
---> 94         self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
     95     return True
     96 except OSError:

File C:\PATH\lib\smtplib.py:716, in SMTP.login(self, user, password, initial_response_ok)
    714 self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
    715 if not self.has_extn("auth"):
--> 716     raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
    717         "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
    719 # Authentication methods the server claims to support
    720 advertised_authlist = self.esmtp_features["auth"].split()

SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your settings.py it should be

`EMAIL_USE_TLS = True` not  `EMAIL_USE_TSL = True`

Comment: Thank you @Elvin-Jafarov!

Now the error just changed to a previous one. I have tried to visit the support.gmail.com link but that didn't work either: 

"""
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x24-20020a170906135800b009930308425csm608042ejb.31 - gsmtp')
"""

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: Never mind. I just forgot to change the <app_password>

It is working now. Thanks for the massive help!!!